# What's the purpose of TransactionSynchronizationRegistry?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jta

According to the JTA spec:

> This interface is intended for use by system level application server
>   components such as persistence managers, resource adapters, as well
>   as EJB and Web application components. This provides the ability to
>   register synchronization objects with special ordering semantics,
>   associate resource objects with the current transaction, get the
>   transaction context of the current transaction, get current
>   transaction status, and mark the current transaction for rollback.

Also:

> The user of getResource() and putResource() methods is a library
>   component that manages transaction-specific data on behalf of a
>   caller. The transaction-specific data provided by the caller is not
>   immediately flushed to a transaction-enlisted resource, but instead is
>   cached. The cached data is stored in a transaction-related data
>   structure that is in a zero-or-one-to-one relationship with the
>   transactional context of the caller.

However I am still puzzled.

First, what does "[...] provides the ability to register synchronization objects with special ordering semantics" mean and how is it possible to setup the ordering?

Then, what are some use cases in which it's necessary to "associate resource objects with the current transaction"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, what does "[...] provides the ability to register
>   synchronization objects with special ordering semantics" mean and how
>   is it possible to setup the ordering?

The "special ordering semantics" are explained in the registerInterposedSynchronization javadoc, which is trying to explain how those listeners are fired relative to Transaction.registerSynchronization.

> Then, what are some use cases in which it's necessary to "associate
>   resource objects with the current transaction"?

putResource/getResource let a caller store "transaction-local" objects.

For example, a JPA container might registerInterposedSynchronization when used.  A stateful session bean might update an entity during SessionSynchronization.beforeCompletion.  The EntityManager would store the entity on the current transaction using putResource, and then flush the data to the database during its Synchronization.beforeCompletion, which is guaranteed to run after.